# Access variable inside a function in another class

Tags: javascript

Is it possible with vanilla JS to access a `let` that was defined inside a function that's inside a class, from another class?

**A non-functional attempt**

```js
// file-1.js
export default class myClass1 { 
  function myFunction(){
    let myVariable = 'Hello'
  }
}

// file-2.js
import myClass1 from "./file-1";

export default class myClass2 { 
  function printClass1(){
    // Print 'Hello'? 
    console.log(myClass1.myFunction().myVariable)
  }
}
```

I could find many answers on how it's done for other languages like C# and Python, but not for Vanilla Javascript

Comment: No, and you can leave the `class` out of the picture completely, it's already impossible to access a variable declared in a function from the outside.

Comment: what are you trying to do? we need some context to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: So I have 2 classes that handel modal logic. One of those classes has functions that handles the background overlay, but I need to access that variable inside that function, because it can change state (or duplicate the code to the other class)

Comment: You can only access if you define it with a `this` so.

Comment: This shouldn't be possible in C# or Python either. Local variables are local, and exist only during the call of the function.

Comment: @SaroVerhees Please share the actual code of those modal overlays if that is what you need help with. Are you talking about a local variable or about an object property? And how are the two classes related to each other?

Comment: I was hoping that I could export the local variable, as an easy fix. But I guess that's not possible (and if it was, not good practice). So instead I defined the variable in the class constructor, and updated that variable in the functions. Now I can access it like `myClass1._myVariable`

Thanks for the advice all